# What is the proper way to update Delphi 2009's default installation of Indy 10?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009, indy

Since Indy is now built-into the install process of Delphi 2009... is there a proper way to 'remove' it so it can be upgraded to the latest from the SVN repo?   There isn't an automated option to remove it as far as I'm aware.

Comment: FYI, Indy has been bundled with Delphi for a LONG time, much earlier than D2009.  Going all the way back to D6 or D7, IIRC.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The *dcu* files for Indy are stored separately from the other Delphi units. To stop using them, simply remove that directory from the search path, library path, etc., and remove the source files from the browse path.

You can remove the design-time packages the same as any other design-time packages. Remove them from the IDE configuration, and then delete the *bpl* and *dcp* files. (If you just delete the files, you may get errors when you next start the IDE since it won't find the expected files.)

Once the Indy components no longer appear on the Tool Palette, the packages no longer appear on the package list, and compiling a project that references Indy units fails with a "can't find used unit" error, you're ready to start installing the latest version.

Comment: Do you know if there are any internal dependencies on the Indy components now that they are included with the environment?  (Any websnap features for example?)

Comment: Nope. No dependencies. The version included with Delphi is pretty much just a snapshot from Indy.

Comment: Doesn't Midas rely on Indy's server?  (I thought it used to)

Comment: (Not midas.dll but the remoting portions)

Comment: Oh, sorry, I thought you asked whether Indy depended on anything from Delphi (which I now realize makes no sense). I have no idea what uses Indy. Whatever does, though, shouldn't require the CodeGear-provided copy. It's intended that you will use a newer Indy version eventually.

Comment: Windows\System32 is also a place where Indy files (Indy*120.bpl) are located which should be removed / updated.

Comment: @DarianMiller there are some Embarcadero technologies that depend on Indy, yes. Known breakages caused by removing the bundled version of Indy and installing a new one are documented in Indy's [Installation Instruction](http://www.indyproject.org/Sockets/Docs/Indy10Installation.aspx). However, for several years now, Embarcadero has used its own internal copy of Indy for those technologies to avoid user breakages, though.

Answer (score 4):

As Rob already said: Just remove the direcories from Delphi's configuration. An additional step is required though: After each update, make sure they have not been added again! Some of the Delphi 2007 updates apparently did that and I missed it for quite a while until I stumbled upon a bug that I already thought fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't use Delphi 2009, but in older versions of Delphi the installation of Indy components was optional. So you could try launching the setup for Delphi 2009 and see if there is an option to "Add/Remove features" or something similar and use it to remove Indy.

Also, you can customize which packages should be loaded in a project, so you can simply deselect the Indy 10 one and add the one from SVN on a per-project basis (you can also configure the default configuration for projects).

PS. Indy rocks! :-)

Comment: I don't really think it rocks. It is very difficult to install.

Comment: @Sahara yes, the install process can be a bit tricky, depending on IDE version. I'm hoping to get that streamlined better in Indy 11, and eventually get Indy into Embarcadero's GetIt Pacakge Manager (it is already in Lazarus's Online Package Manager).