# Step by step upgrade of Indy 10 in Delphi 2009

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009, indy, indy10

Can someone help in telling the details on how to uninstall Indy 10 and install the latest build? I found it http://indy.fulgan.com/ZIP/IndyTiburon.zip

There is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931371/install-the-latest-build-of-indy-10-on-delphi-2009), but not a satisfying answer, just some comments from the user who asked, but that is not a step by step guide.

Why there is not a tool for this?

Comment: Indy used to have an automated installer, but that was maintained by AtoZed and they do not support it anymore.  We are planning on streamlining the install process in Indy 11 and write our own installer.

Comment: @RemyLebeau i am returnign on this ask after 3,5 years. I read in http://indy.fulgan.com/Getting%20the%20latest%20Indy%2010%20snapshot%20using%20Tortoise%20SVN.pdf that now i must use Tortoise to get Indy. I did this and now i will try to re-follow the steps in the accepted answer. How to know which Indy version is in the trunk folder?

Comment: You can use Tortoise (or any other SVN client) to access Indy's SVN server directly, but that is not a requirement.  Fulgan maintains a nightly .zip snapshot of the current trunk, you can download that instead.  See [Indy's SVN instructions](http://indyproject.org/Sockets/Download/DevSnapshot.aspx) for details.

Comment: @RemyLebeau i managed also wiht SVN, anyway the zip contains much more than 3 folders, so i'll use the core/protocol/system folders in the lib folder and put them in the indy10 delphi source folder then proceed as in the accepted answer below

Comment: totally stuck, i tried to follow the isntructions in the accepted answer but there are many errors during compialtion, i tried with yesterday SVN + build 5117 from zip in indy fulgan. is it possible to get help?

Comment: Since this question is several years old, you should post a new question, explain the exact steps you took, and show the actual errors you are seeing.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I did this very recently, I've done it before with 2007 and had lots of problems, but this time in D2010 it went really well...

Assumptions:

1. The Indy BPL's are stored in the bin
   folder
2. DCP and DCU are stored in the
   lib\indy10 folder
3. Source code is source\indy\indy10
   (then you have core/protocol/system
   subfolders)

Directions:

So, I took the BPL/DCP/DCU files and saved them somewhere safe (just in case)
I renamed the core/protocol/system folders to core.old/protocol.old/system.old
I then copied the core/protocol/system folders from the indytiburon.zip into source\indy\indy10 folder

Now, the packages have to be built in the following order:

System - Core - Protocol - dclCore - dclProtocol

For Delphi 2009, open the packages whose names end in *130*; for Delphi 2010, *140*.

I opened each package, then in the options I pasted the full path to lib\Indy10\ into the DCP and Unit output directory fields, and the full path to bin\ into the package output directory field.

Then I `built` the packages. For the dcl packages I also `installed`.

Certainly for 2010 it went without a hitch!

Comment: If you're going to replace the Delphi-provided units and packages, you'll want to replace the debug versions, too. Otherwise, you'll get unit conflicts whenever you check the "use debug DCUs" linker option. Personally, I'd just use a separate copy of Indy and leave the Delphi-provided files alone.

Comment: I succesfully installed Indy following your instructions. Can you tell me about debug DCUs? What to do for that? ANyway for now I can build my project and the bugs I had due to not update Indy disappeared.
THIS INFO SHOULD BE IN BIG FONT ON INDY WEBSITE!!!

Comment: That's great it all worked! I was going to add the steps but I got held up on paid work - at the moment I've just renamed the lib\debug\Indy10 to lib\debug\Indy10.old to ensure there's no mismatch

Comment: Just for completeness, if you intent to use the Indy components in C++ Builder as well, remember to copy the .hpp files to the include directory. To have the compiler generate the hpp files set it to generate all c++ files.

Comment: This will make problem with DataSnap in Delphi 2010 or XE http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4567127/is-it-possible-to-use-indy-10-5-8-0-in-delphi-xe-and-datasnap

Comment: On the Indy website, they say to use 12 for Delphi 2009, and not 13.

Comment: Instructions helped me with the installation on Delphi7 (using the sources from Indy svn). Thank you.

Comment: @huguesVanLandeghem: compatibility issues are mentioned in [Indy's install instructions](http://indyproject.org/Sockets/Docs/Indy10Installation.aspx).