# Apache + Delphi XE + Datasnap. Memory Issues

Tags: apache, delphi, datasnap

I have a program in Apache + Delphi XE7 with Datasnap. My httpd.exe of Apache consume memory until give messsage "Out of Memory" then I need to restart it.

I developed a simple program just testing this problem. In this program I ve configured Server Module (FD components, Mysql) and WebModule appropriately

In client I have a DBGrid that shows the content of a query.

I open TaskManager and monitor the memory.

The problems: 
if I connect and disconnect TSQLConnection the memory increase. 
If I open and Close TClientDataSet the memory increase.

What I have already did:
I used Pascal Analyzer searching memory leaks but it´s all fine

I couldn't use ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown in the server, because is a DLL, and I dont know how to do this :(

I tried to turn off keep alive of Apache but there is no difference

I ve tried all types of LifeCycle in WebModule (Session, Server and Invocation) no difference too.

Anyone has a problem like this? work with this softwares? And could help?

Tks

Comment: With such little information that you gave, I would say no, no one can help you.

Comment: Since you are using XE7, are you logging memory with FastMM?

Comment: I put more information in my question...

Comment: May be unrelated, but it reminds me of a problem I had a few years ago where my datasnap server kept using memory and wouldn't release it.  Turns out I was creating the proxy methods on the client side to access the datasnap server methods and didn't free the client side object.  You have to free the client side proxy object before the server will release the memory it allocated to service the request.(http://stackoverflow.com/a/6630429/822072)

Comment: I'm having problems in the clientdataset, when i call functions I use free normally. Tks anyway.