# Is it possible to replace the Indy version supplied with Delphi XE3?

Tags: delphi, indy10, delphi-xe3

This has come up in the past, in particular reference questions on Delphi XE:  [Is it possible to use Indy 10.5.8.0 in Delphi XE and DataSnap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4567127/is-it-possible-to-use-indy-10-5-8-0-in-delphi-xe-and-datasnap)  and [Is it possible to recompile the DataSnap packages in Delphi XE with a new/different version of Indy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6497201/is-it-possible-to-recompile-the-datasnap-packages-in-delphi-xe-with-a-new-differ)

I remember seeing something that progress was made with this issue.. I'm now using Delphi XE3 and wanted to revisit this issue.  Is it now possible to uninstall the version of Indy supplied with XE3 and update it to the latest Indy version available without messing up DataSnap or anything else that comes with Delphi that has dependencies on Indy?

Comment: Forgive my now-deleted answer... in my haste to answer the title question I (foolishly) neglected to read the body of your question. Remy's answer is relevant. Again, sorry about that!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Information about upgrading Delphi's pre-installed copy of Indy 10 is available on Indy's website:

[Indy 10 Installation Instructions](http://www.indyproject.org/Sockets/Docs/Indy10Installation.EN.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the link.  I didn't realize that site was still updated.