# What does it mean to "open the 130 packages" for Delphi 2009?

Tags: delphi, package, delphi-2009, indy

I'm following instructions for [how to upgrade Indy 10 in Delphi 2009](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3204601/step-by-step-upgrade-of-indy-10-in-delphi-2009) and I am stuck at the following steps:

> Now, the packages have to be built in the following order:
>
> System - Core - Protocol - dclCore - dclProtocol
>
> For Delphi 2009, open the 130 packages, Delphi 2010 open the 140
>   packages.
>
> I opened each package, then in the options I pasted the full path to
>   lib\Indy10\ into the DCP and Unit output directory fields, and the
>   full path to bin\ into the package output directory field.
>
> Then I built the packages. For the dcl packages I also installed.

What does "open the 130 packages" mean?

Can anyone explain to me in detail how to build a package?

Comment: Indy does not use project groups.

Comment: This question really should have just been a comment on the referenced answer. I've edited the answer to clarify it.

Comment: Yeah I was wondering about that except I was not sure if it was going to be a thread that people would get back to to answer right away.  Thanks for editing it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The instructions are referring to the individual projects that contain 130 in their names, namely:

```
IndySystem130.dpk
IndyCore130.dpk
IndyProtocols130.dpk
dclIndyCore130.dpk
dclIndyProtocols130.dpk
```

Comment: Ahh Thanks, that makes sense.. The indy update files I downloaded were actually 120 so I must not of downloaded the latest for Delphi 2009 in the first place. I'm trying to update it so that I can upload files via http post.  But i'll try a different approach. (the ones you mentioned in my other question thread ).  Thanks

Comment: Well I thought I would give it one more go and I found the 130 pkg files.  Looks like I might get it to work!